# Jquery Infinite Carousel Caption Modification

Tags: jquery, carousel, infinite, caption

Yesterday, I had a client ask me to remove the captions from the image space on an infinite carousel I have implemented here: http://www.nokkam.com/showcase.html and thanks to stack overflow, I was able to accomplish this.

Now, I am being asked to make the caption animation mimic the animation of the images (from left to right as opposed to animating upward from the bottom. Would it be worth modifying this script or should I abondon it and attempt to find one more suited to what Im being asked for. I have searched loads of carousel plugins and cant seem to find one that animates in this fashion. Any help or ideas is always greatly appreciated.

Ive tried setting up the same page and modifying what I think to be correct properties in the script using "left" instead of "margin bottom" to control the animation but now the entire textholder has disappeared. Im really flailing here. I located parts in the script that I think control the animation and guessed what would make them work… this failed.

PREVIOUS SCRIPT

```
$(obj).append('<div id="textholder'+randID+'" class="textholder" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;margin-bottom:'+-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight+'px;left:'+$(obj).css('paddingLeft')+'"></div>');
            var correctTHWidth = parseInt($('#textholder'+randID).css('paddingTop'));
            var correctTHHeight = parseInt($('#textholder'+randID).css('paddingRight'));
            $('#textholder'+randID).width(imgWidth-(correctTHWidth * 2)).height((imgHeight*o.textholderHeight)-(correctTHHeight * 2)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ccc','opacity':'.8'});
            showtext($('li:eq(1) p', obj).html());  


function showtext(t)
            {
                // the text will always be the text of the second list item (if it exists)
                if(t != null)
                {
                    $('#textholder'+randID).html(t).animate({marginBottom:'0px'},500); // Raise textholder
                    showminmax();
                }
            }



function showminmax()
            {
                    if(!autopilot)
                    {
                        html = '<img style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:18px;display:none;cursor:pointer" src="/assets/images/down.png" title="Minimize" alt="minimize" id="min" /><img style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:18px;display:none;cursor:pointer" src="/assets/images/up.png" title="Maximize" alt="maximize" id="max" />';
                        html += '<img style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:6px;display:none;cursor:pointer" src="/assets/images/close.png" title="Close" alt="close" id="close" />';
                        $('#textholder'+randID).append(html);
                        $('#min').fadeIn(250).click(function(){$('#textholder'+randID).animate({marginBottom:(-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight)-(correctTHHeight * 2)+24+'px'},500,function(){$("#min,#max").toggle();});});
                        $('#max').click(function(){$('#textholder'+randID).animate({marginBottom:'0px'},500,function(){$("#min,#max").toggle();});});
                        $('#close').fadeIn(250).click(function(){$('#textholder'+randID).animate({marginBottom:(-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight)-(correctTHHeight * 2)+'px'},500);});
                    }
            }


    // animate textholder out of frame
                $('#textholder'+randID).animate({marginBottom:(-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight)-(correctTHHeight * 2)+'px'},500);
```

MY EDITED SCRIPT (changed some of the variables blindly and made it worse)

```
$(obj).append('<div id="textholder'+randID+'" class="textholder" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:'+-imgWidth+$(obj).css('paddingLeft')+'"></div>');
            var correctTHWidth = parseInt($('#textholder'+randID).css('paddingTop'));
            var correctTHHeight = parseInt($('#textholder'+randID).css('paddingRight'));
            $('#textholder'+randID).width(imgWidth-(correctTHWidth * 2)).height((imgHeight*o.textholderHeight)-(correctTHHeight * 2)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ccc','opacity':'.8'});
            showtext($('li:eq(1) p', obj).html());


function showtext(t)
            {
                // the text will always be the text of the second list item (if it exists) .width(imgWidth-(correctTHWidth * 2))
                if(t != null)
                {
                    $('#textholder'+randID).html(t).animate({left:correctTHWidth}); // Raise textholder

                }
            }
```

// animate textholder out of frame
                    $('#textholder'+randID).animate({left:(-imgWidth-(correctTHWidth * 2))+'px'},500);

PROGRESS!!!
So, by editing the following I at least have been able to accomplish animating the textholder out of the frame! Now I just need to figure out how to animate the new textholder into the frame… please help if you know anything further.

```
// animate textholder out of frame
$('#textholder'+randID).animate({left:(-imgWidth)-(correctTHWidth * 2)+'px'},500);
```

YET ANOTHER PROGRESS UPDATE
Through more blind fumbling (trial and error), I have managed to get the animation to at least move in the correct direction! I am now having problems with the text bar coming in from the left and animating back out in the same direction… This is my last hurdle here. If anyone has any contributing words as to which things may trigger this, I would still be greatly appreciative.
*The chaos is underway at the link below. Thanks in advance.*

So, after changing the animate properties and getting rid of the "showminmax" function altogether… I still have an animation that wont function properly. I know this isnt a very exciting question, but Im really fresh out of ideas and starting to lose hair. Thanks everyone.

My new, even (slightly) more functional example can be seen here: 
http://www.nokkam.com/showcase2.html

Comment: If anyone has ANY pointers, I would be forever in your debt…

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this problem? I have similar requirement.